# How to read file or data from client, or other way to get info to server

Tags: php, client, file-transfer

The scenario: I have a number of machines/workstations (running Windows 7 or 8) that log in to a web application (PHP). The application needs to identify each machine to provide specific data for it.
The user is not to be involved in the process of identifying the workstation (needs to be automated to avoid mistyping).

So far we have a script running in the morning at the startup of the machines that writes the machine id/name into the firefox cookie database, then FF is started and the web application is loaded, retrieving the machine id from the cookie. That procedure works ok so far, but from time to time the cookie is not written (probably some problem with the script) and the user has to enter his id manually.

Is there another way to do it? I have access to each machine that log in to the application, so I can put down any kind of txt, ini or whatever file that holds the id/name of that machine. I just need to get that info reliably into the web application...

Comment: could try localstorage

Comment: @Havihavi I'm looking into usage of localstorage right now. Sounds interesting and might be a solution... I would need to manually send the id once, so the site knows it and can store it then, but that would be doable.

Comment: Would you be able to use their MAC address as authentication?

Comment: yeah, the clients browser will remember that id until you or they clear it. setitem and getitem stays. i think u have 5mb of datastorage in it.